# Static IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an enum of strings. Here's what I've got so far,

```
private class TypedEnum<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetType().GetFields().Where(f => f.IsLiteral).Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).OfType<T>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

private static class Combinators : TypedEnum<char>
{
    public const char DirectChild = '>';
    public const char NextAdjacent = '+';
    public const char NextSiblings = '~';
    public const char Descendant = ' ';
}
```

But there are two problems with this. (1) It won't compile because `Combinators` is static... I can remove that and hide the c'tor though. (2) It's not enumerable unless I instantiate it, which I don't need nor want to do. What are my options? Forget about making it enumerable?

---

I think this is as close as I can get

```
public struct Combinators
{
    public const char DirectChild = '>';
    public const char NextAdjacent = '+';
    public const char NextSiblings = '~';
    public const char Descendant = ' ';

    public static IEnumerable<char> ToEnumerable()
    {
        return typeof(Combinators).GetFields().Where(f => f.IsLiteral)
            .Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).OfType<char>();
    }
}
```

But I wish I could put that `ToEnumerable()` method in a subclass :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hah! Solved it!

```
public class TypedEnum<TBase, TValue>
{
    public static IEnumerable<TValue> ToEnumerable()
    {
        return typeof (TBase).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).OfType<TValue>();
    }

    public static TValue[] ToArray()
    {
        return ToEnumerable().ToArray();
    }

    public static string Pattern
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("(?:{0})", string.Join("|", ToEnumerable().Select(c => Regex.Escape(c.ToString()))));
        }
    }
}

public class Combinators : TypedEnum<Combinators, char>
{
    public const char DirectChild = '>';
    public const char NextAdjacent = '+';
    public const char NextSiblings = '~';
    public const char Descendant = ' ';
}
```

Just have to pass the class itself as a type to `TypedEnum`.

Comment: N.B. for regex purposes they should be sorted from longest to shortest, lest something like `=` may be matched before `==`. Also, the `ToEnumerable` method may catch a couple extra fields unless the results are further filtered to `consts` only (right now it returns all public statics of the appropriate type).

Answer (score 2):

I removed inheritance from your Combinators class

```
static class Combinators { // no inheritance
```

*Note: These solutions use a [C# iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) which is simpler than a full-fledged [Enumerator](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/191b9b61-b8c5-43b0-9c13-d1cf848d6c00) implementation; iterators just need the [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword.*

---

### Static implementation

USAGE: To iterate over the **static** class fields, and gathering the output:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach ( var ch in Util.AsEnumerable<char>(typeof(Combinators)) )
        sb.AppendLine(ch.ToString());
```

IMPLEMENTATION: A C# iterator to faciliate the feature (it resuses some of the original code):

```
static public class Util {

    static public IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(Type t)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, t))
            yield break;

        foreach (T val in t.GetFields().Where(f => f.IsLiteral).Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).OfType<T>())
            yield return val;
    }
}
```

### Result

Results of the StringBuilder receiving the fields of your Combinator class are:

> >
>   +
>   ~
>   *(space)*

---

### Instance implementation

*(**NOTE:** - Not needed to answer this question, but added for posterity and as a counterpart to the static method shown above)*

USAGE: Method called as an extension on any instance, gathers results in StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var ch in new Combinators().AsEnumerable<char>())
    sb.AppendLine(ch.ToString());
```

IMPLEMENTATION: C# [Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to faciliate instance enumeration:

```
static public class EXTENSIONS
{
    static public IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this object thisObj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, thisObj))
            yield break;
        foreach (T val in thisObj.GetType().GetFields().Where(f => f.IsLiteral).Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).OfType<T>())
            yield return val;
    }

}
```

Comment: Extension method isn't helpful... it only works on instances.

Comment: I know, but I decided to add it for posterity. :)  For your needs just focus on the static implementation in the first part.  I updated my answer to show the second part is not needed to answer your question but it's worthwhile to note.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without creating instance - a type itself cannot implement interface. The best option will be something like

```
private class Combinators : TypedEnum<char>
{
    public static readonly Combinators Instance = new Combinators();

    private Combinators()
    {
    }

    public const char DirectChild = '>';
    public const char NextAdjacent = '+';
    public const char NextSiblings = '~';
    public const char Descendant = ' ';
}
```

so you'll have single instance which can be enumerated, passed to methods, etc.

Alternatively, you can write an extension for `Type`:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EnumerateConstantFields<T>(this Type type)
    {
        return type.GetFields().Where(f => f.IsLiteral).Select(f => f.GetValue(null)).OfType<T>();
    }
}
```

and use it like `typeof(Combinators).EnumerateConstantFields<char>()`

Comment: Then I have to use `Combinators.Instance` everywhere? Yuck :S

Comment: added an alternative, but anyway you'll need to add something to `Combinators` type name - either `Combinators.Instance` or `typeof(Combinators).EnumerateConstantFields<char>()`. Type name itself is just an identifier, you can't force it to act like a variable.

Answer (score -3):

IEnumerable is helpful ONLY when running through the elements of a set in a for-each loop. Nothing else!

All arrays are IEnumerable. It has no sense, repeat, **no sense**, to declare IEnumerable a type that only exposes a set of constant fields.

If you have a reference to an array of your type, it's automatically IEnumerable. If you ever wanted to be able to run through the possible values of your enumeration, that's another matter. You will be instantiating an array.

Example

```
public enum Operators
{
    Plus,
    Minus,
    Multiply,
    Divide,
    Power
}


string[] available_ops = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Operators));
foreach(string op in available_ops) //IEnumerable<string> working here
    Console.WriteLine("Available operator: {0}", op);
```

Output

```
    Available operator: Plus
    Available operator: Minus
    Available operator: Multiply
    Available operator: Divide
    Available operator: Power
```

Comment: "IEnumerable is helpful ONLY when running through the elements of a set in a for-each loop." -- well, that's what I want to use it for, looping over the constants. And it does have other uses; if it implements IEnumerable then all the LINQ expressions become available and I could call ToArray() or Count() or what have you on it. I don't want to use `enums` because I need the values to be chars in one case, and strings in another. Specific ones. Getting their names isn't useful, and I want to encapsulate that logic in the class rather than rewriting it everywhere.

Comment: But that's the point. If they are constants, you know them from design/compilation time! If you have an array of T (string, char, whatever), you don't know what it contains until runtime. The ToArray(), again, can be invoked only on instances of a class, not as a static method. If you need static ToAarray() or Count(), just write them in your class (but it will require some manual coding). And LINQ only works on instances :(

Comment: Yes... I want the constants to be constants so I can use them in switch statements... the ToArray() functionality is used elsewhere in the program where it doesn't need to be constant. I did end up writing the function myself... well, not really, I yielded the elements and then called ToArray on that :p I didn't downvote this, but I this answer misses the boat..